# Translation of 'morphisme net'?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, translation-request, mathematical-french

In French, one refers to a certain 'morphisme net'. I am looking for the English translation of this.

EDIT: The term appears [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0404454v2.pdf) on p.22 Lemme 2.7.2. Unfortunately I have not been able to find the French definition either.

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you encounter the term? It would help us to know what contexts it is used in.

Comment: It would be good if you could give the definition (in translation).

Comment: A guess: Perhaps they mean a [net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_%28mathematics%29) of morphisms in some category?

Comment: I've added a link to the paper I am looking at; I don't think it is a net of morphisms.

Comment: It reminds me of exact sequences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [[SGA 1](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0206203), Exposé I, Dfn 3.2], "morphisme net" or "morphisme non ramifié" refers to a morphism $X \to Y$ of finite type such that the relative diagonal $X \to X \times_Y X$ is an open immersion. This is called an **unramified morphism** in English, although [sometimes](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02GE) one generalises to morphisms *locally* of finite type.